# Cant read from a file and write the same content to another file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-io

I am trying to open and read a file names `spam0` and I want to get its contents and write them to another file named `input.txt`, but I am getting an error.

This is what I have tried till now:

```
file0 = fs.open("./spam0.txt", 'r', function(err, data) // opening spam0 
{
    if (err) {
        console.log("error");
    } else {
        //write spam0 data tp input.txt
        file = fs.writeFile('input.txt',  data, {flag:"w+",encoding:"utf8"} ,function(err, data)
        {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The error I get is:

```
fs.js:75
throw new TypeError('"options" must be a string or an object, got ' +
^
TypeError: "options" must be a string or an object, got number instead.
at getOptions (fs.js:75:11)
at Object.fs.writeFile (fs.js:1269:13)
at C:\Users\akash\Desktop\riidl\node.trail.js:12:14
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
```

Comment: The signature is [`fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), you have the `data` and `options` arguments missplaced

Comment: Have you googled it before posting it here?  There are many articles available over internet https://tutorialedge.net/javascript/nodejs/reading-writing-files-with-nodejs/

Comment: I think there is nothing mentioned about options in the link you have shared @SandipNirmal do correct if i have overlooked , i am new to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words you want to copy contents from one file to another, right?
It would be much easier to create read stream from origin file and pipe it to write stream of destination file.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const origin = fs.createReadStream('./spam0.txt', {flags: 'r'});
const destination = fs.createWriteStream('input.txt', {flags: 'w+'});    
origin.pipe(destination);
```

Of course, if you want to do some transformation, you may use [Transform streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) (see [tutorial by Jeff Barczewski](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html)).

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');
const origin = fs.createReadStream('./spam0.txt', {
    flags: 'r',
    // read data as a string not as a buffer
    encoding: 'utf8'
});
const transform = new stream.Transform({
    // accept data as a strings
    writableObjectMode: true,
    transform: function removeNewLines(chunk, encoding, callback){
        callback(null, chunk.replace(/\n/g, ''));
    }
});
const destination = fs.createWriteStream('input.txt', {
    flags: 'w+',
    // write data as a strings, this is default value
    encoding: 'utf8'
});

origin.pipe(transform).pipe(destination);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @sempasha , this is a good idea, now suppose i wanted to remove all the "n" character from the input.txt  file , how  i do it ? (assuming  i am using the method you have shown?)

Comment: I've improved my answer by adding example of transforming data between reading from source and writing to destination file.